# cumulative sum, difference in pandas

Tags: pandas, sum, cumsum

I am trying to calculate cumulative sum in pandas:

My given data is: input_df['length'] and input_df['encoder']

My desired output is: input_df['desired_output_model1'] and input_df['desired_output_model2']

[image]

input_df['desired_output_model1'] = difference between the rows, reseted everytime input_df['encoder]=0

input_df['desired_output_model1'] = cumulative sum of input_df['desired_output_model1'], reseted everytime input_df['encoder]=0

```
import pandas as pd 
input_df = pd.DataFrame([10., 13., 1., 0.3, 0.3, 16., 2, 0.4,13,2,0 ])
input_df.columns = ['length']
input_df['encoder'] = input_df.where(input_df['length']>0.5,0)

input_df['desired_output_model1']=pd.DataFrame([10., 3., 12., 1.0, 0.0, 16., 14., 2.0,13,11,2.0 ])

input_df['desired_output_model2']=pd.DataFrame([10., 13., 25, 26, 0.0, 16., 30, 32.0,13,24,26 ])
input_df.head(20)
```

Comment: Bit confused here. What is your input and which is your expected output?

Comment: I have updated my post, hope it is clearer now.

Comment: So, you want `df.groupby(df.encoder.eq(0).cumsum()).length.diff().abs()` and so on?

Comment: , but I am not sure how can I groupby my data. I have tousends of data and

Comment: `df.groupby(df.encoder.eq(0).cumsum()).length.diff().abs()` there is a groupby there

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was what I needed. Need to check it tomorrow once again, to be sure it is what I wanted. I coud not have done it without your help.